# How do you run another program from a python script?

Tags: python

This is my code so far

```
from subprocess import call
call("/Users/oscar/Desktop/Controlled Assessment/Currency Converter.py")
```

When I run it I get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oscar/Desktop/Controlled Assessment/ISBN Checker.py", line 10, in <module>
    call("/Users/oscar/Desktop/Controlled Assessment/Currency Converter.py")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 470, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 744, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/subprocess.py", line 1394, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: another program, or another python script? If it's the latter, there's a built in `execfile()` function. Don't include spaces in your filename. And make sure you can run that script by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like you're trying to execute another Python script, why not import it?

```
import Currency_Converter
```

And then run the modules you want in there? Take the space out of the file name and replace it with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Check the interpreter directive from your script.

It should start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print 'your python script...'
```

That means that when you call this script directly, it will be interpreted by python binary.

You can get more info on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Answer (score 0):

use `subprocess.Popen`

```
import sys, subprocess
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "myscript.py"])
```

This should run `myscript.py` within the Python command line.